# Combine XSL for-each statements where specific records are limited by position

Tags: xml, loops, xslt, position

The code below is achieving the desired result but it feels sloppy. Is it possible to combine the for-each statements?

XSL:

```
            <xsl:for-each select="ROW[Start_Time = '2:00 PM']">
            <xsl:sort select="order" order="descending" data-type="number" />
            <xsl:value-of select="Brand" /><br/>
            </xsl:for-each>

            Top5: 
            <xsl:for-each select="ROW[Start_Time = '2:00 PM']">
            <xsl:sort select="order" order="descending" data-type="number" />
            <xsl:if test="not(position() &gt; '5')">
            <xsl:value-of select="Brand" />, 
            </xsl:if>
            </xsl:for-each>
```

Working Output:

```
            Nike
            Addidas
            Coke
            Pepsi
            Burger King
            Sprite
            Root Beer
            Brio Chinotto

            Top5: Nike, Addidas, Coke, Pepsi, Burger King,
```

Was thinking to somehow define a new variable/parameter with each loop cycle and then use:

```
            <xsl:value-of select="$Brand_Position1" />, 
            <xsl:value-of select="$Brand_Position2" />,
            ...
            <xsl:value-of select="$Brand_Position5" />,
```

I would like to make this as efficient as possible. Am new to xsl. Thank you.

Comment: Please post an example of the input and indicate if you're using XSLT 1.0 or 2.0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it would be best to start with something like:

```
<xsl:variable name="sorted-rows">
    <xsl:for-each select="ROW[Start_Time = '2:00 PM']">
        <xsl:sort select="order" order="descending" data-type="number" />
        <xsl:copy-of select="." />
    </xsl:for-each>
</xsl:variable>
```

so that the nodes are sorted once only.

Then, assuming you're using XSLT 1.0, you can follow with:

```
<xsl:variable name="sorted-rows-set" select="exsl:node-set($sorted-rows)/ROW" />
```

and:

```
<xsl:for-each select="$sorted-rows-set">
    <xsl:value-of select="Brand"/><br/>
</xsl:for-each>
```

and:

```
<xsl:text>Top 5:</xsl:text>
<xsl:for-each select="$sorted-rows-set[position() &lt;= 5]">
    <xsl:value-of select="Brand"/>
    <xsl:text>,</xsl:text>
</xsl:for-each>
```

See: http://exslt.org/exsl/functions/node-set/index.html

Comment: This looks great. Am using 1.0. Haven't been able to get the above to work just yet but will continue to try before posting the whole code. The error's probably on my side. Much appreciated reply.